# infer generic parameters in rest tuple type

Tags: typescript, generics, tuples, inference

Reading about [rest elements in tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#rest-elements-in-tuple-types) and trying to figure out how to extract the generic part of a type:

```
type Attribute<Type> = { id: string, type?: Type };

type Position = { x: number, y: number };
let Position: Attribute<Position> = { id: "position" };

type Status = "active" | "inactive";
let Status: Attribute<Status> = { id: "status" };
```

I'm sure there's a way to write a conditional type that will map a tuple of various `Attribute<T>` to a tuple of various `T`.

```
type AttributeTypes<Attributes extends Attribute<any>[]> =
   Attributes extends Attribute<infer T> ? T[] : never;

type Result = AttributeTypes<[typeof Position, typeof Status]> // should be `[Position, Status]`
```

But I don't understand the inference step well enough and it always ends up in the `never` branch.

The final step will be to write a function that uses the inferred types as part of the return ([Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAZwBQEpEG8BQjFQCeADgKaICCUUATjAEYhSkA8AKiaQHyIC82iGABMAXClowwAcwA0BTgH4xHMogC+Abhx55qgApxkMWAj4CAHmLAgAtvVI05hK7fs11W-ABtSURAaMTMDEqCUZmFgDjeDAefixBUUQAImJDaIRkj218IlUAZSgAQygQZDNkougYADdSLIAfFMkq2Drkz0QfP0KSspDqOnDWXtLkOIFhMWTkYrGszRzdclChplIVUmQWVYZ18tJzZjAhct3hliKwQi4AbQBdCdx8fFu9QSQAa1JCOGBKQZ7ZjIe4DML7N73RCHY6nAHgiKSYAORBsHgKVGIKykOo0TpqJZ5cgAJS2IC8fn453Wm22tyJf386SCcgZ-1GZUeiCWoEgQUQUl8FC8Xh2gOGByOpBOZ3F60u1zuj1QOnwADoNSUEVswWsIlcbg8dOhdUCNpxttTgTxni8aL4QDQkFq9Vs1TYisRUC6+DwXWqieh8UtuogAGJwOBiN7MmJyDkgsyCqDCryoKIsxAJoM4NRAA)):

```
function getAll<Attributes extends Attribute<any>[]>(
  ...attributes: Attributes
): AttributeTypes<Attributes> {
  return attributes.map(attribute => attribute.type);
}

let [position, status]: [Position, Status] = getAll(Position, Status);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The conditional type has no reason to work on a tuple, your conditional type basically resolves to the question `[typeof Position, typeof Status] extends Attribute<infer T>` which it clearly does not so you end up with never.

You could pass in a union into the type (`AttributeTypes<typeof Position | typeof Status>`) and then you will get `Position[] | Status[]` which is not really what you want ([Play](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAZwBQEpEG8CwAoRRKATwAcBTRAQSigCcYAjEKcgHgBUzyA+RAXmyIYAEwBcKejDABzADRFuAfglcKiAL4BufPkIl1ABTjIYsBAKEAPCWBABbRuToLith07qadBRABtyKERjU3MwCRopZlY2ELN4MD5BLGFxRAAiUhN4hHTvXV8DSgBlKABDKBBkS3Sy6BgAN3I8gB8M6TrYJvSfQgCg0oqqiNoGaPZByuQkoVEJdORyqbztAv1ualGmFnI1cmQ2SLGd6vIrVjARaqPtmLKwYh4ZvUJNqJPEM4urt+OY6WAzkQHD4SmBAG0ALqIWzkJp0XqINaKdQAJX2ID8QUEN3GewORTgwGC2TCiDahOJkyqfHwGiAA))

You could also use an array in your conditional type (`Attributes extends Array<Attribute<infer T>> ? T[] : never`) but that will not preserve the tuple structure in the input ([Play](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAZwBQEpEG8CwAoRRKATwAcBTRAQSigCcYAjEKcgHgBUzyA+RAXmyIYAEwBcKejDABzADRFuAfglcKiAL4BufPkIl1ABTjIYsBAKEAPCWBABbRuToLith07qadBRABtyKERjU3MwCRopZlY2ELN4MD5BLGFxRAAiUhN4hHTvXV8DSgBlKABDKBBkS3Sy6BgAN3I8gB8M6TrYJvSfQgCg0oqqiNoGaPZByuQkoVEJdORyqbztAv1ualGmFnI1cmQ2SLGd6vIrVjARaqPtmLKwYh4AbQBdGb1CTaiTxDOLq+odDoZWIhy24zY0mAzkQHB4fCUsNeiFs5CadF6iDWinUACV9iA-EFBDdxnsDk8inBgMFsmEFFSaZMqm8sXgNEA))

The best way to get the output you want is to use a mapped type. Mapped types preserve tuple while allowing you to map every element type of a tuple to a new element type in the resulting tuple:

```
type Attribute<Type> = { id: string, type?: Type };

type Position = { x: number, y: number };
let Position: Attribute<Position> = { id: "position" };

type Status = "active" | "inactive";
let Status: Attribute<Status> = { id: "status" };

type AttributeTypes<Attributes extends Attribute<any>[]> = {
  [P in keyof Attributes]: Attributes[P] extends Attribute<infer T> ? T : never;
}

type Result = AttributeTypes<[typeof Position, typeof Status]> // is [Position, Status]
```

[Play](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAZwBQEpEG8BQjFQCeADgKaICCUUATjAEYhSkA8AKiaQHyIC82iGABMAXClowwAcwA0BTgH4xHMogC+Abhx55qgApxkMWAj4CAHmLAgAtvVI05hK7fs11W-ABtSURAaMTMDEqCUZmFgDjeDAefixBUUQAImJDaIRkj218IlUAZSgAQygQZDNkougYADdSLIAfFMkq2Drkz0QfP0KSspDqOnDWXtLkOIFhMWTkYrGszRzdclChplIVUmQWVYZ18tJzZjAhct3hliKwQi4AbQBdCdx8fFu9QSQAa1JCOGBKQZ7ZjIe4DML7N73RCHY6nAHgiKSYAORBsHgKVGIKykOo0TpqJZ5cgAJS2IC8fn453Wm22tyJf386SCcgZ-1GZUeiBwaiAA)

Comment: Thanks, that made sense. Still can't quite get the `AttributeTypes` type to work in practice though, made an update to the question to describe the specifics.

Comment: @DanPrince the version you posted works (it is different from the on you have in the playground, the parameter name is different). You are only missing an `as any` assertion on the return type, which is unavoidable.

Comment: Even with the `as any` assertion I still get a type error when using `getAll`: `Type 'any[]' is missing the following properties from type '[Position, Status]': 0, 1`

Comment: @DanPrince just `as any` no `[]` https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/KYDwDg9gTgLg3gXwFAwJ5mAAgIIxlASwCMBXGYAHgBV1gA+TAXkzkwIBMAuTAZ3wIB2AcwA0mNBgD83GhkwIA3EhS1MABQg8CMAhAFMWmENwEkAtkWBQxqE+ctR5SgDbAY6zdt0DuufqXIKDS0dPQZmVg5uACJIEO9op2UJLABlGABDGBIeA2iMgGMdADdgRIAfTGjBQpKylzdMdKyc3zxCAMpm7J5wwyiqvhaeRMVk1T8OsmBZYB4KSeJp3NByAXZcxc6KDIFUOgBtAF0+uCRMTAO1Nn0Aa2BUCAAzHHal8h4jtv9lq6PMVbAdabN7bQRPKyYKgMSRQzAmYClKBKZBIJ4kARFbyYIRubDOZzUAEgNYbV4-QK7fbHOgACnOmAAdMyshS5jIkABKb5TcizebQlgMqBuEhQfSs3lzRlmDJgWmSpgMSWMlKczAZXJUlHKVzuABiEAg3CunlCAjE3Ry-2YuJg+OctOCXj0lsyPU5CiAA